# Simple twitter bootstrap test won't display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to twitter bootstrap, and have been following an online tutorial on setting up a navbar. The problem is, I simply cannot get it to render as it should as per example. I have checked, and rechecked the code and see no syntax error any obvious problem. Here's what I'm supposed to see with the example I'm following.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw0lR.jpg) "Proper render"

However, this is what I get.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzBtL.jpg) "Bad render"

I really don't know why this is happening. My include paths are correct, the files are there from a fresh full download package from TB website.

Here is my full code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Unti</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

</head>
<body>



<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="brand">responsive test!</a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<ul class"nav">
<li> <a href="#">Testnav</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Testnav</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Testnav</a> </li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the code from the tutorial.

(http) ://i.imgur.com/dMniiwF.jpg

Answer (score 3):

`<ul class="nav">` you forgot to add = after class